# How do I target compiled C - OSX - File extension

Tags: c, macos, file-extension, compiled

What file extension would compiled c code have? It's not showing any sort of file extension...

I'm currently using to prune my folders of dSYM files.

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -g

clean:
    rm -r *.dSYM
```

How can I 'target' my compiled C programs, and just wipe the folder of all compiled code?

Thanks

Comment: When compiled to *object* files, they usually have the extension `.o`. When compiled and linked as an executable, it's usually no extension at all on UNIX and UNIX-y platforms (like Linux and OSX), and `.exe` on Windows.

Comment: `rm -f $(DIR)/*.o` [This](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/) link may help.

Comment: That's not working for me I'm afraid. OSX 10.8 using the xCode compiler, the files don't have an extension listed. Thanks though :)